# Is there a formatting preset for moment to 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment and most of the time I need to get just the date as string, the format to pass it to the database, or maybe just a comparision (moment, help's me to compare, but still).

Everytime I need this particular format, I have to write `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`, and I'd like to know if there is a preset, like a `C`, for complete, or `I` for iso. I couldn't find anything in the docs, only internationalization with variations of `L`

Comment: I usually store the format in a variable and write a convenience function to take care of it for me.

Comment: There is no preset. You could write a plugin that provided one, or just create a helper method as @Aankhen suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As version **2.20.0**, you can use [Special Formats](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/) (even if they are mentioned in the parsing section of the docs), for example you can use `moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE` to get output in `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```js
console.log(moment().format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want, you can also customize [default format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#default-format), to make [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (without parameter) display result in your preferred format:

```js
console.log(moment().format());
moment.defaultFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
console.log(moment().format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you want you can [extend](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) moment using `moment.fn` and build a function that accepts your tokens (like `'C'` and `'I'`):

```js
moment.fn.myFormat = function(token){
  if( token == 'C' ){
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  } else if( token == 'I' ){
    return this.toISOString();
  } else {
    return this.format();
  }
}
console.log(moment().myFormat());
console.log(moment().myFormat('C'));
console.log(moment().myFormat('I'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> The `Moment` prototype is exposed through `moment.fn`. If you want to add your own functions, that is where you would put them.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see it in the documentation (and I don't either), that suggests that no, there is no current preset for that in Moment.

You could always add your own:

```
Object.defineProperty(moment.fn, "myYMD", { // or moment.prototype, they refer to
                                            // the same object according to the docs
    value: function() {
        return this.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
});
```

(Using `Object.defineProperty` because I never add enumerable properties to prototypes.)

Note the prefix on the method name, to avoid conflicts with future extensions to Moment.

Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty(moment.fn, "myYMD", {
    value: function() {
        return this.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
});

// using it
console.log(moment().myYMD());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Or just use a utility method you pass the Moment instance into.

Comment: I know that is quite hidden in the docs, but I think that [default format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#default-format) could be useful to preset moment formatting. Moreover, is there a reason to use `Object.defineProperty(moment.prototype, ...)` over `moment.fn`? (Just asking to learn no polemical intent, I'm not native english speaker)

Comment: @VincenzoC - Wow, good find, though I wonder how many scripts would get broken if one set `moment.defaultFormat` to something else. :-) Re `Object.defineProperty`, I **always** make properties on prototypes *non-enumerable*. Re `moment.prototype` vs. `moment.fn`, they refer to the same object so it doesn't really matter, but [the docs talk about assigning to `moment.fn`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) (even then they go on to say it's the same object as `moment.prototype`), so probably more idiomatic to use `moment.fn` -- I've updated it above.

Answer (score 0):

As defined on that section [Long Date Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) you can define a format like:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "h:mm A",
        LTS: "h:mm:ss A",
        L: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        l: "M/D/YYYY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        ll: "MMM D YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        lll: "MMM D YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        llll: "ddd, MMM D YYYY LT"
    }
});
```

And then use it like for example:

```
moment().format("L");
```

That would be the best way as far as I know to preset your own format.